# How to implement iOS 8 and iPhone 6 into Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm currently using Xcode 5.1.1. I did all the code and game development for the 4 inch iPhone simulators. I just fitted everything from 4inch iPhone simulator to 3.5 inch iPhone simulator. Now i want to fit everything into iPhone 6 and implement iOS 8. Currently my project only offers that i work on ios6, ios7 and lower. How do i implement ios8 and since the iPhone simulator doesn't give me a choice to choose higher than a 4inch iPhone simulator, how do i implement iPhone 6's 4.7 inch and iPhone 6plus 5.5 inch screens?

I'm using storyboards if that makes a difference

Comment: Start by downloading the latest Xcode (6.1.1)

Comment: Yeah, anecdotally speaking: adding an appropriately sized default.png allowed the Xcode before the official one to produce apps that worked with the full iPhone 5s screen but Apple ensured there was no advantage by blocking the only useful reason for doing so (i.e. retaining an ARMv6 slice) on the iTunes side. Apple isn't interested in helping people to stick with old versions of its software.

Comment: Would downloading Xcode 6.1.1 completely override and delete my Xcode 5.1.1 project with all my game code? Or can i simply transfer it if i'm using Objective-C?